# EKS Terraform Blueprint for Fluentbit default deployment creates string logs from JSON

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-eks, fluent-bit

we deployed fluent bit via the terraform eks blueprint to send logs to cloudwatch. its pulling in everything as expected except for that JSON logs are being turned into strings.

If i run a `kubectl logs container` ill get back:

```
{
  "service":"OpensearchBulkIndexWorker",
  "event":"batch_indexing_job",
  "index":"data-object-share",
  "total_count":42,
  "error_count":0,
  "duration":0.11248340101155918
}
```

But when looking in cloudwatch logs i then get:

```
{
"log": "2023-07-24T18:41:47.084106019Z stdout F {\"service\":\"OpensearchBulkIndexWorker\",\"event\":\"batch_indexing_job\",\"index\":\"data-object-share-parcel\",\"total_count\":42,\"error_count\":0,\"duration\":0.11248340101155918}
...
```

based on this [doc](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/kubernetes-logging-powered-by-aws-for-fluent-bit/) i thought it was built it that it would parse to json but guess something has changed? any idea how to resolve?